# cmd keyword in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

I recently come across a sql script conatining `cmd` keyword. I couldn't make much of it and couldn't find its specific use.

```
select 
'update profile_table set name=' || t2.name || ';'as cmd
from user_table t2
```

Comment: Why did you tag `postgresql`?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a keyword, it's just column alias. The value of the column is SQL command so naming it CMD is expectable.

Answer (score 1):

> as cmd

`cmd` followed by keyword **AS** qualifies it as a **column alias**. In fact, even without the keyword AS, it is considered as a column alias.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT 'FOO'||'BAR' as cmd FROM DUAL;

CMD
------
FOOBAR

SQL> SELECT 'FOO'||'BAR' cmd FROM DUAL;

CMD
------
FOOBAR
```